# Algorithm to separate sentences?

Tags: algorithm

Assume I have an array of words. E.g. {"I", "like", "melons","Susan", "likes", "apples"}(Only a very simple example) I want to find where I should add a period, AKA where I should separate the sentence. So the answer would be "I like melons." "Susan likes apples."

The capitalization could give some hints. But a capitalized word does not guarantee a start word(first word of the sentence). For example, abbreviations like NBA, USA, country name like America, Canada, they are capitalized but can be in the middle of a sentence.

What algorithm can be used to do the work?

Comment: `I like melons, Susan likes apples` is a valid sentence as well.

Comment: You can only approximate it and even then it doesn't sound simple. Most algorithms I saw do it the other way around: given a text with punctuation, try to find where a sentence begins and ends. But at the end of the day a sentence is a rather arbitrary unit of text (as is a word really) and its rendering in writing is highly ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Without building a classifier and training it on a large corpus, I think looking for a period followed by a capitalized word is the only simple approach. It is also possible to find long lists of capitalized abbreviation words like that (as well as proper nouns potentially), which could help you.

[NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) has some good tools for that, using a combination of those approaches I believe, and gets very good precision.

Comment: This problem sounds slightly harder too as there is no punctuation in the input data.

Comment: Yeah, just saw your other comment- it'd probably be challenging to build any kind of classifier when a human couldn't even identify this as one or two sentences for sure.